# Doubt about the RADEMACHER'S THEOREM demonstration.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, partial-derivative

I was recently reading an article called [An Elementary Proof of Rademacher's Theorem.](https://www.intfxdx.com/downloads/rademacher-thm-2015.pdf)  In the text below $U$ is a ball and $ f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ is a lipschitz function. Let $S$ the set of $x\in U$ for which $\partial_v f(x)$ does not exist.

> **My question.** How can we prove that the continuity of $ f $ implies that the set $ S $ is measurable?

I'm trying to look at $ S $ as the following set.
$$
S=
\left\{ 
x\in U 
\left|
\begin{matrix} 
\forall T:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R} \mbox{ linear }\exists \epsilon>0 
\\ \mbox{ such that }
\forall \delta>0 
\\
|t|<\delta \mbox{ and } \frac{|f(x+tv)-f(x)-Tv|}{|v|}>\epsilon
\end{matrix}
\right.
\right\}
$$
Then, prove that such a set is measurable. But something tells me that $ S $ can not be described in this way. So the question seems to be this. How to describe $ S $ properly and then prove that it is a measurable set?

[image]

**Update.**
Examining the text in the image better, I realized that I can express the set $ S $ in the form below. I believe it's the correct expression for $ S $. Recall that $|v|=1$.

- $S=\{x\in U: \partial_{v}f(x) \mbox{ does not exist }\}$
- $S=\left\{x\in U: \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t}\mbox{ does not exist }\right\}$
- $S=\left\{x\in U\left| \begin{matrix}
  \mbox{ logical negation of} \\
  (\exists \partial_vf(x)\in\mathbb{R}) (\forall \epsilon>0)(\exists \delta >0)
  \\
  0<|t|<\delta\implies\left|\frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t}-\partial_vf(x)\right|<\epsilon
  \end{matrix}\right.\right\}$
- $S=\left\{x\in U\left| \begin{matrix}
  (\forall \partial_vf(x)\in\mathbb{R}) (\exists \epsilon>0)(\forall \delta >0)
  \\
  0<|t|<\delta\mbox{ and } \left|\frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t}-\partial_vf(x)\right|\geq \epsilon
  \end{matrix}\right.\right\}$
- $S=\displaystyle\bigcap_{L\in\mathbb{R}}
  \displaystyle\bigcap_{\delta>0} \big( S_{L,\delta}^+\cup S_{L,\delta}^+) 
  $ for 
  $
  S_{L,\delta}^+=\left\{x\in U\left| 
  \frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t}\leq L+ \epsilon,
  0<|t|<\delta
  \right.\right\}
  $ 
  and 
  $
  S_{L,\delta}^-=\left\{x\in U\left| 
  \frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t}\geq L - \epsilon,
  0<|t|<\delta
  \right.\right\}
  $